# how to add nested list(new List<List<Box>) entity framework core in memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class Box
       {
            public string Name{ get; set; }
            public int position{ get; set; }
            public int boxID { get; set; }
       }
```

//another class

```
    public class DbMyContext:DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("exampleDatabase1");

        }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Box>(entity =>
            {
                // Set key for entity
                entity.HasKey(p => p.boxID);
             
            });

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
        public DbSet<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
}
```

//another class

```
 using (var context = new DbMyContext())
     {
      deviceStateRead_.boxes = new List<List<Box>>();

//both kinds of errors.
     context.Boxes.AddRange(deviceStateRead_.boxes);
     or 
     context.Boxes.AddRange(deviceStateRead_.boxes[index]);
     }
```

entity-framework-core-inmomery

I can't add database in nested list in memory.I am getting both kinds of errors.I want to add nested list.

Comment: Hi @ramon back, what's the error message? Besides, you do not set any data to the list, what if you set property `Name` value for the list.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<Box>>' to 'Box'

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 3 i++)
            {
 context.Box.Add(new List<Box>())
            }
}

Box tempBox = new Box();
tempBox.Name="example";
tempBox.boxıd=1;
context.Box[0].Add(tempBox);

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/two+dimensional+list+c%23

In this connection, I want to do the operation with ef core.

Comment: have you tried to `AddRange(new List<Box>())`  instead? the `deviceStateRead_.boxes` seems to be a nested list of `Box`, it should be a list of `Box`.